# Required asterisk inside input field

Tags: html, css, required

Is it possible to put a red asterisk to inside of an input field to the far right? I don't have room on my form to put an asterisk and if I do put them it will look strange. Here is my css for my inputs.

```
input {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Normally, I'd suggest an `:after` selector, but since `input`s are self-closing tags they can't have content. You may have to consider either a change to your HTML to allow for this CSS, or a JavaScript solution to modify it after load.

Comment: have you tired the placeholder attribute?

Comment: @j08691, I am using the placeholder attribute. Can I define HTML inside them?

Comment: no. placeholders are text, since they're literally the content of the input. any html you put in there is NOT rendered, since it's parsed as plaintext. it'd be no different than typing some html into an input.

Comment: Well then placeholder isn't gonna do what I want at all haha. @j08691

Comment: @Nic you are ok to pick up a complete Bootstrap framework to achieve the * .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bootstrap there is a class called "input-group-addon" that would do what you're talking about. If you aren't using Bootstrap, maybe you could still borrow the css for that class if it looks like what you're envisionng for your project. There's an example of it used here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: `form-control-feedback` is much more similar class to what is needed comparing to `input-group-addon`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a before or after for input control. So inorder to achieve the end result, you need to wrap the input control with a div (make it inline-block) and use css "after" to position the "*"

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
#wrapper input {
  padding-right: 14px;
}
#wrapper:after {
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: +3px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootsrap3 along with Glyphicons, you can try this:

```css
.requiredFieldWrapper::after 
{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: '*';
    position: absolute;
    top:2px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 17px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-xs-10 requiredFieldWrapper">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
```